# How do I find missing images in Firefox debugging

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In firefox, I have a few missing images being shown in the console like:

`GET http://localhost/img/file.svg        [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1513ms]`

Is there a way I can find where these images are being called from? I'm using a bootstrap template and would rather not go through every script to locate them. I'm sure they are being called from a style sheet.